# Mozilla Firefox and Thunderbird as default browser and mail client

Tags: mail.app, safari, firefox

I use Firefox and Thunderbird for browsing and email. In the Safari Preferences, Firefox is set to be default browser. Each time I start Firefox, it asks if I want it to be the default browser. Same thing with Thunderbird. If I disable this check in Thunderbird, and click a mailto-link on a webpage, Apple Mail opens.

How can I set Firefox and Thunderbird to be the default clients, without having to confirm this each time I restart my computer?

Answer (score 1):

You had 2 questions.

1- Go to your Firefox preferences and uncheck the Always check for default browser.

[image: ff]

2- For Thunderbird do this:

> [Set Thunderbird as the operating system default](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/make-thunderbird-default-mail-client)
>
> ```
> Launch the default Mac OS X email application (called "Mail", located in the /Applications folder.)
> Select Mail | Preferences from the menu.
> On the General tab, select "Thunderbird" from the Default email reader drop-down list.
> Close Mail.
> ```